# How to create an array of singly linked list

Tags: c, string, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create an array of linked lists where, each list's node is a character of the alphabets, so the array should have 26 elements. I tried to do this by giving each element's first node the string "." then use insert

Here's my linked list Definition

```
struct Node{
    char *name;
    struct Node *next;
};

void printList(struct Node *node)
{   printf("[");
    while (node !=NULL){
        printf("%s,", node->name);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
struct Node *current = NULL;

void append(struct Node* head, char* new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    new_node->name = new_data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL){
        head = new_node;
        return;
    }
    else{
        while(head->next != NULL){
            head = head->next;
        }
        head->next = new_node;
        return;
    }
}
```

here's the main function, in it, i created a string al of the alphabet, then use for loop to update each of the linked list in the array.

```
int main(){
struct Node list[26];
    for(int x=0; x<26; x++){
        struct Node* first = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        first->name = ".";
        first->next= NULL;
        list[x] = *first;

    }
    char *al = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";


    for(int x = 0; x<26; x++){
        char name[2];
        name[0] = al[x];
        name[1] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", name);
        append(&list[x], name);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

After the loop, all of the name value of the LinkedList is Z, instead of going from A to Z.

*edit
i Printed the second node of each linkedlist inside the array

```
for(int n =0; n<26; n++){
        printf("%s\n", list[n].next->name);
    }
```

Here's the result

```
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
Z
```

It's supposed to be from A to Z rather than just Z.

Comment: [Edit] and _show_ the output you get vs. the output you expect.

Comment: Your code invokes UB in a bad way.  Each list's data pointer is the buffer `name`, and that pointer is invalid after the end of the scope in which `name` is declared.  In your `append` function, you need to `strcpy` the data somewhere.  Each list node needs to have its own copy of the string.  As it is, you are overwriting that data in the loop, and then referencing it after it is no longer valid.

Comment: I'm not sure what, exactly, you are doing, but are you sure that this couldn't be a bit-vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

- `struct Node list[26]` with `struct Node *list[26]`
- `list[x] = *first` with `list[x] = first`
- `append(&list[x], name)` with `append(list[x], name)`

`struct Node list[26]` is an array of `struct Node`, but you want an array of *pointers* to `struct Node`, each element of the array being the pointer to the head of a list.

Bonus: your `append` function is very inefficient. In order to append an element to the list you have to go through the entire list to find the last element. You should maintain the pointer to the last element of the list.